# How do I interpret the result of a 2D fourier Transform on an Image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I am having trouble understanding the result of the 2D Fourier transform on images. Are the indices in the resulting matrix the horizontal and vertical frequencies respectively, of the image? How can I extract the frequencies that are present in the image from the matrix?
As I recall in the 1D case if one were to Fourier transform a signal, one would get a spectrum representing the Magnitude of each frequency in said signal. How does it work for images? How do I interpret the result?
Sample code:

```
img = imread(image);
A = rgb2gray(img);
X = fft2(A);
```

How do I interpret the X matrix in this case for example?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: The Fourier transform yields both magnitude and phase for each frequency. This is true for images also. But in images each frequency has a direction as well. This question is more suited to [DSP Stack Exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask there. I just want to know how to read the X matrix and how to interpret it.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not a complete answer but I'll try. 
The frequency domain for the image could look like the one in the image i provided ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsuJA.png)). What those frequency domain plots show is an overall direction which is dominant in the image. For the first frequency plot this would be vertical. If you take a close look you can also see some edges from the input image. Big changes in intensity result in sharp "edges" in the frequency domain which is caused by the representation of a rectangular impulse in the frequency domain ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aR2Kb.png)).

Not sure if this helps

**Letter image, binary:**
[image: Letter image, binary]
**Rectangular impuls in frequency domain:**
[image: Rectangular impuls in frequency domain]

Comment: Can you maybe explain how that is represented in the X matrix? How can I derive the frequencies present in the image from the X matrix?

Comment: Tahera was faster than me. I hope your question is answered?

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose you have an image of 30x30 i.e 900 sample points on which you have to perform fft. After computing your fft you get 900 point valued matrix. Now, its important to understand that these values are not to be separated as sine and cosine components, instead these are complex numbers that your signal is made of. only 451( half+1) values of your matrix contain actual data that you are interested in i.e DC component, 449 complex components, nyquist frequency component and 449 complex conjugates of complex components. the only information your complex conjugate values provide you is about the null imaginary part.

***how can you derive information from your matrix:***

modulus of the coefficient: gives amplitude information

angle of the coefficient: gives you phase information

real part: cosine amplitude

imaginary part: sine amplitude

component at index i: frequency (i/N)*Sr where N is the FFT size and Sr is your sampling rate.

Hope this helps. To understand further application refer to page: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/fourier.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you maybe further explain what you mean by: "component at index i: frequency (i/N)*Sr where N is the FFT size and Sr is your sampling rate".
Its a 2d matrix so we have two indices i and j. How can I read a the frequency at lets say X(1,1)?

Comment: component at index i means : lets say your row number is 3 and column number is  5 and your image width is 30 then your 'i' index will be : (3 * 30 + 5) i.e (row number * width + column number)

Answer (score 0):

Projection slice theorem is hell of a tool understanding and relating 2D ft to 1D ft. It states that: Suppose that you have a line on the image at any angle (angle increases in ccw ,conventional sense) and along that line you take 1D ft (since line has also an amplitude due to pixels of the image). Now, 1D ft of that line is equal to 
                          S(f*cos(theta), f*sin(theta))
where S is the 2D ft of the image, theta is the angle that your line is at and f is the parameter of your line (just as the parameter x of the x axis).

Once you understand this theorem, I beleive it becomes easier to understand the concept of 2D ft.